# 1991 F250 cranks, won't run

Tags: ford, cranks-wont-run, f-250

It started up and died after that it would only crank. To top it all of my rod that pushes the ignition switch to start broke. So I improvised and used a screwdriver in place of the rod in the steering column. It still would only crank. I hear my fuel pump hum while under the gas tank, i replaced my old distributor, spark plugs, spark plug wires, ignition switch, and ignition coil and am recieving voltage up to the wire that connects to the distributor but still only cranking. I bought a code tester and have no fault codes. After clearing the test codes I went to start it and lights come on but not even a sound when I crank it now. What the hell is the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost I always start with the basics:-spark-fuel-compression.
have you verified that spark is present at the plugs when cranking? Since you replaced almost the entire ignition system you should have spark. If no then maybe check your ignition control module (these go out frequently). If spark is good move on to fuel. The pump may be on but do you have fuel pressure at the engine. Easy to check with starter fluid sprayed into throttle body. Fuel filter may be plugged. If fuel is good then the next step would be to verify your compression is OK. Since you mentioned it no longer cranks then you should check and make sure your starter did not fry from too much cranking without time to cool off. Make sure your starter solenoid is supplying power to starter. Another possibility may be that the engine hydro locked with gas. Best of luck!